# Command to remove node_modules and clear all watchman watches - MacOS

Tags: macos, react-native, node-modules, watchman

Most of the time, I have to run a clean build of my React Native project.
Currently I'm using this command: `cd android && ./gradlew clean` to clean `gradle`.
Is there a command to clean `gradle`, delete `node_modules` and `watchman watches`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to run the following command inside the terminal of your project's root directory.

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn install && react-native start --reset-cache"
```